# Are the commandments in Mishlei Torah she-baal peh that was later written down?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, oral-torah, mishlei

Shalom.

I have for a long time been confused about what exactly Sefer Mishlei is. Were the commandments in this book - 'Acquire Chokhmah' / 'Get discernment' etc. - revealed to Moshe at Har-Sinai? Were these things Oral Torah until Shelomo Ha-melech wrote them down? Might Shelomo Ha-melech's instructions concerning getting chokhmah etc. have been an extended meditation on / elucidation of how to fulfil the commandment to 'know this day that HKBH is G-d...'?

Please forgive my ignorance!

Comment: 1) Mishlei is called משלי שלמה בן דוד - the proverbs of Shlomo, son of Dovid HaMelech, the King of Yisrael. Malbim says that Mishlei means a grouping of parables; for in order to teach unknown, obscure and profound things, [the author] will create a proverb based on known things. In this way, the hidden, unknown analogue may be glimpsed through the clothing of the parable.

Comment: 2) The Malbim goes on to explain that Shlomo was really wise. Truths, Malbim says, become known through: tradition (our sages etc...), wisdom from G-ds spirit that rested on Shlomo etc..  and last but not least: Through discernment and experience

Comment: 3) So, to me, it seems that these were not mitzvos that were given on Har Sinai. Rather, these are proverbs, wise saying by Shlomo, who was really wise and had G-ds spirit in him, and he wrote them down, providing us lessons for life.

Comment: To quote this article: https://torah.org/learning/basics-primer-torah-proverbs/

Comment: “So, what’s Proverbs really about?” We could say that Proverbs is a credit course in common sense. Much can be learned about the human mind by thinking about why two particular ideas were placed next to each other; why this verse would have been just like the last one… except for that small, almost insignificant difference and what the words actually mean. One can learn how to decide logically between two choices, how to make use of experience to avoid repeating mistakes and from what to stay away while chasing after a goal (especially the goal of Torah-observance). "

Comment: @Shmuel - thanks for this. My question was motivated by another question. I needed an answer to this question in order to answer my prior question. My second question concerned the chronological priority of mitzvot: Is 'get Chokhmah' etc. the 'chronologically first commandment', that, if fulfilled, makes possible the fulfilment of the other mitzvot? Should one go from 'Get Chokhmah' etc. to 'Know this day that HKBH is G-d...' to all the other mitzvot? Sorry if I am being obscure.

Comment: The Rabbeinu Bahya writes: Solomon urges us here to tune in to words of Torah and to tune out to extraneous matters. He writes this in a commentary to Devarim 7:12 and cites Mishlei 2:2. There are 613 mitzvos, but Shlomo teaches us how to life them etc....

Comment: Apologies - the latter question in my comment above should read: Must one fulfil 'Get Chokhmah' etc. first, and then 'Know this day that HKBH is G-d...', before one is in a position to fulfil all the other commandments properly?

Comment: Rambam writes:  A person must direct his heart and all his actions to only know G-d. How do we do that? We want to acquire wisdom in order to know His ways and thus know Him. So yes, one should acquire wisdom, work on that.

Comment: @Shmuel - thanks. I would be grateful for a source that speaks of a ‘chronological priority of mitzvot’, if anyone has one. But happy with this.

Comment: Here are some sources:     Psalms 111:10 - ״ראשית  חכמה יראת ה ׳״ - the beginning of wisdom -  chochmoh - is fear of hashem

Comment: @שלום - thanks - With blessings :)

Comment: The Mishnah in Berachos 2:2 - one must  first recite the paragraph of “Shema”, which talks about accepting Hashem’s unity and kingship and afterwards the paragraph of “Vehayah”, which is about accepting the mitzvos in general

Comment: @שלום - that’s great - many thanks. More than I deserve :s